# Argle Bargle in mid-Fargle

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases

Tom Holt writes in "Open Sesame" on page 237 of the pocket edition "argle bargling in mid-fargle". I understand this means something like "he talks complete nonsens in mid-bustle". Is that right? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

**argle-bargle is Scottish slang**

> verb **argle-bargle** (third-person singular simple present argle-bargles, present participle argle-bargling, simple past and past participle
> argle-bargled) (slang) **To argue**.
>
> 1886, Robert Louis Stevenson, “The
> Captain Knuckles Under”, in Kidnapped, being Memoirs of the Adventures
> of David Balfour in the Year 1751: […], London; Paris: Cassell &
> Company, Limited., OCLC 1056292939, page 97: Last night ye haggled and
> argle-bargled like an apple-wife; and then passed me your word, and
> gave me your hand to back it; and ye ken very well what was the
> upshot. Be damned to your word!
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/argle-bargle

Also see this - https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/arglebargle_n_v

---

I don't know what fargle is. It could be a nonsense word just used for  rhyming purposes. Do you have any more of the text?

Answer (score 1):

The [Dictionary of the Scots Language](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/arglebargle_adv_phr) has an entry for ***Argle-Bargle*** meaning:

> (adv.phr.) In disputatious talk.

> - em.Sc. (a) 1931 J. Ressich in Gsw. Herald (8 Aug.):
>   And on they gaed, argle-bargle, an' the crood got bigger an' bigger.

as for [fargle,](https://wordfoolery.wordpress.com/tag/fargle/)  the following site suggest it refers to a game:

> fargling is any game which is used to resolve a dispute between two or more people. Now it probably wouldn’t work too well at a UN Security Council meeting but it’s perfect for determining who gets the first turn on the swing.

> The classic American fargle is rock-paper-scissors, which is also known as roshambo.

(wordfoolery.wordpress.com)

So, according to context, the whole sentence might refer, for instance, to a dispute over a trivial issue.